# How to generate heatmap in python from tuple?

Tags: python, heatmap

I have a tuple of n elements where each element is

```
([numpy.array([[r], [phi]]), E],)
```

where r and phi are polar coordinates and E some given real value. 
How can I construct heatmap from this?

Answer (score 0):

First, split the tuple of n elements into a list of lists:

```py
# If data_tuple is the tuple of n elements
data_list = [[row[0][0][0][0], row[0][0][1][0], row[0][1]] for row in data_tuple]
```

Then use `seaborn` to construct a heatmap

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(data_list)
```

You can read more about seaborn heatmaps [here](https://likegeeks.com/seaborn-heatmap-tutorial/)